# No provider for DatePipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to use DatePipe in my service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BaseService {

    public items = [];
    constructor(
        protected datePipe: DatePipe,
        protected translateService: TranslateService
    ) { }
}
```

But I get this error: `NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!"`. What is the cause?

Comment: do you import the commonModule in your application module ? https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule

Comment: You can only inject classes decorated with `@Injectable`. If you need to use a pipe in a component (as opposed to a template) instantiate a `new` instance.

Comment: See it on [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-lc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Answer (score 143):

Just add the **DatePipe** in the **NgModule** **providers** section in your **app.module.ts** file.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```